# PSD.JS Parsing the color of a text layer

Tags: javascript, node.js, psd

I am using [PSD.JS](https://github.com/meltingice/psd.js) (a photoshop PSD file parser for NodeJS and browsers) to parse a few PSD files. When the parser extracts the information for a text layer, the color information is returned as an array.

e.g: `colors": [ [ 102, 0, 255, 0, 255 ], [ 102, 0, 255, 0, 255 ] ]`

But the array contains 5 values instead of 3 for RGB or 4 for CMYK.

Please can somebody help me understand why the color is represented with 5 values?

And is there a way to convert this into RGB equivalent?

I am pretty sure this is not an issue with PSD.JS but an implementation detail.

Comment: CMYK + Alpha channel?

Comment: Maybe share the PSD so we can open and see what it looks like within the application. Initial thoughts are alpha channel, but the value/order doesn't look right.

Comment: Here is the file. But this is the case will all PSD.https://www.sendspace.com/file/0ow58d

Comment: Are the values in the array different between files? There aren't any text layers with opacity less than 100% so I don't think your values are related to alpha.

Comment: @dom_ahdigital the values are different for different layers and so they are different from file to file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PSD.js mainainer here.

After some digging in the source code i discovered that this image channel parsing follows the js canvas convention of pixel channeling as discribed [here](http://meltingice.github.io/psd.js/docs/lib/psd/channel_image.coffee.html).

as the doc states:

```
Parse the image data. 
The resulting image data will be formatted to match the Javascript Canvas color format.
 e.g. [R, G, B, A, R, G, B, A].
```

So this has nothing to do with the psd file format or the image in question, it is simply because we parse it this way so you can conveniently apply the buffer to a canvas.